# Match any non-ASCII word in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, regex, unicode, find-and-replace, non-ascii

I want to match any non-ASCII word over 2 letters long, and add brackets around it. I.e. this string

```
[i]Abandon one's post:[/i] [c]P.[/c] τάξιν ο οὕνεχ’ ὅρκων, ἀν λείπειν, [c]V.[/c] τάξιν το ἐρημοῦν.
```

should become

```
[i]Abandon one's post:[/i] [c]P.[/c] [[τάξιν]] ο [[οὕνεχ]]’ [[ὅρκων]], ἀν [[λείπειν]], [c]V.[/c] [[τάξιν]] το [[ἐρημοῦν]].
```

I tried with this but it did not match anything

```
(?i)\b[a-z]*(?![a-z])\pM*\pL\w*
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967954/regex-to-search-for-words-containing-foreign-characters

Comment: It looks like the notepad++ flavor of RegEx doesn't support the `\pM` and `\pL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK Npp doesn't know mark property `\pM`, but you could do:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\b((?:(?![a-zA-Z])\pL){3,})\b`
- Replace with: `[[$1]]`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\b              : word boundary
(               : start group 1
  (?:           : start non capture group
    (?!         : lookahead, make sure next character is NOT
      [a-zA-Z]  : latin letter
    )           : end lookahead
    \pL         : any letter in any language, case insensitive
  ){3,}         : must appear at least three times
)               : end group 1
\b              : word boundary
```

**Replacement:**

```
[[$1]]          : content of group 1 surrounded with brackets
```

**Result for given example:**

```
[i]Abandon one's post:[/i] [c]P.[/c] [[τάξιν]] ο [[οὕνεχ]]’ [[ὅρκων]], ἀν [[λείπειν]], [c]V.[/c] [[τάξιν]] το [[ἐρημοῦν]].
```